# Communicating with ports with c++ or c#?

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port, port, parallel-port

I'm starting to write a program which communicates with serial/parallel ports. I'm not sure whether I should write it with C# or C++.

I prefer C# because it's my preferred language and I have written applications (high level) with it. But I'm not sure if it can handle port communication in all circumstances. (For example once I wanted to develop a filter driver and found out it couldn't be done at all using C#. So I'm in doubt about port programming limitations as well.) Usually people go with C++ in these situations. (why?) Is there any limitations in C# I should be aware of regarding this matter?

Comment: Are you simply communicating over these ports, or do you want completely control, such as to be able to set a pin high or low?  If you need that detailed control, you can use C#, but will need an additional component, such as the one available here:  http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm

Comment: I prefer having complete control over the port for further extensibility.

Comment: @Brad why didn't you send this as an answer? If I couldn't get a better answer, I'd mark it as the best answer.

Comment: @Kamyar, because I wan't sure what you needed yet.  Now that I am, I have posted an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: C#? Is it even possible to write device drivers in .net?

Comment: @Gene: No it's not. That was just an example. C# produces intermediate language that is interpreted by a virtual machine (.NET). All these stuff runs in user mode but WDM drivers run in kernel mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need fine control over the port (ie, the ability to bit-bang and send raw data), then you need an extra component to do this in .NET.  See http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm for an example.

There is no managed way to do this, but by using external components, you can develop in your familiar environment.  This is probably the way to go, since dealing directly with ports is a life-consuming process.